# While we are using Qlabel as hyperlink text how we can remove the line below the hyperlink text in normal state?

Tags: qt, qt4

I want the line to appear only when we hovered or press the hyperlink text not in normal state and i want to change the color of the text also. i have tried Qpalette but i found no change in color.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a style attribute to your anchor tag:

```
QLabel *label = new QLabel("<a style='text-decoration:none' "
                           "href='http://www'>your link</a>);
```

See the [HTML subset](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/richtext-html-subset.html) supported by Qt's rich-text widgets for details.

Comment: thank's but can you say where i can find documentation of this.

Comment: @user896036 I completed the answer with that info.